# Put one child at the beginning and one child and the end of `GtkBox` in GTK4 using XML

Tags: xml, gtk, gtk4

The title pretty much describes the problem. I know I can start packing elements from the beginning or end of an element (`GtkBox`, for example) using the [pack_start](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Box.pack_start.html) and [pack_end](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Box.pack_end.html) functions programmatically. But I want to use XML.

I can't use `halign` / `valign` because they affect all children at once.

I tried using `<child type="[start/end]">` like for `AdwHeaderBar`'s children, but they don't work for `GtkBox`.

I haven't found much documentation on GTK4's XML packing syntax.

My question is mostly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581081/gtk-headerbar-actionbar-pack-start-pack-end-within-ui-xml-file), but for GTK4 since the `packing` syntax was dropped in the transition from GTK3 to GTK4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, I recommend the GTKCenterBox class.  Here is an example of the .ui file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-name packtyp.ui -->
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.0"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="title">PackTyp right and left Gtk4</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkCenterBox" id="box">
        <property name="orientation">GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL</property>
        <child type="start" >
          <object class="GtkButton" id="child1">
              <property name="label">left</property>
          </object>
         </child>
         <child type="end" >
           <object class="GtkButton" id="child2">
              <property name="label">right</property>
          </object>
         </child>
      </object>
     </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

[image]

best regards

Comment: Nice! I think for most navbar / alignment problems `GtkCenterBox` is going to be the most intuitive solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple, but it took me a while to experiment until I figured out how to do it.

Every element is naturally aligned to the beginning of the **Gtk.Box**, unless you order otherwise. So, for one element to be at the beginning and another at the end, the element at the beginning must have its align (**valign** or **halign** depending on the orientation of your **Gtk.Box**) set to "start", the element at the end must have its align configured as "end", and one of the elements, either one, must have its expand (**vexpand** or **hexpand**) set to True, so it extends pushing the other element to the opposite position in the **Gtk.Box**. Below is a minimal example in XML, I recommend using [Workbench](https://flathub.org/apps/re.sonny.Workbench) to visualize it in a simple way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.0"/>
  <object class="GtkBox" id="welcome">
    <property name="orientation">1</property>
    <property name="halign">center</property>
    <property name="vexpand">true</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton">
        <property name="label">button01</property>
        <property name="valign">start</property>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton">
        <property name="label">button02</property>
        <property name="valign">end</property>
        <property name="vexpand">true</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

[image]